# How to check the date in between the tuple, dates as start and end

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, tuples

I 'm having a function where it creates a dictionary as below.

```py
x = {'filename': {'filetype': ('5/6/2019', '12/31/2019')}, 'filename2': {'filetype': ('3/24/2018', '5/6/2019')}}
```

I need to create a new function by passing the date and its type to return the filename based on the tuple dates.

```py
def fn(date, filetype):
    I'm trying to pass a date as a first argument
    and the date should check if it is in between  the tuple as start and end dates
    in the dictionary values above If it is in between those dates I need to return the file name

    return filename
```

**Question:**

Is it possible to check the in-between dates for tuples?

Comment: convert it to `datetime` object and then you can use `start < data < end` to compare dates.

Comment: if you will have strings in format `year/month/day` (with zeros) then you can compare even strings `"2019/06/05" < "2019/12/31"`

Comment: use `from datetime import datetime` then convert your strings to datetime objects

Answer (score 0):

you should convert to datetime objects:

```py
from datetime import datetime
x = {'filename': {'filetype': ('5/6/2019', '12/31/2019')}, 'filename2': {'filetype': ('3/24/2018', '5/6/2019')}}

def fn(dateobj, filetype):
    dateobj = datetime.strptime(dateobj, '%m/%d/%Y')
    startdate = datetime.strptime(filetype[0], '%m/%d/%Y')
    enddate = datetime.strptime(filetype[1], '%m/%d/%Y')
    return startdate <= dateobj <= enddate

print(fn('6/6/2019', x['filename']['filetype']))
print(fn('4/6/2019', x['filename']['filetype']))
```

this will print:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

As people mentioned in the comments, transforming the string dates to datetime objects is recommended. One way to do it is:

```
from datetime import datetime
new_date = datetime.strptime('12/31/2019', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Assuming all datestrings are datetime objects, your function becomes:

```
def fn(date, filetype):
   for filename, range in x.items():
      if filetype in range:
         start, end = range[filetype]
         if start <= date <= end:
            return filename
```

This will return the filename if the date lies between the range, and None otherwise

Answer (score -1):

Use `split` to convert dates to 3 numeric values in this order: year, month, date. Then you can compare the dates as tuples.

```
def convert(datestr):
    m, d, y = datestr.split('/')
    return (int(y), int(m), int(d))

date1 = convert('12/31/2018')
date2 = convert('1/1/2019')

print(date1 < date2)
```

The same approach works with lists, but those two types must not be mixed, either all dates in a comparison are tuples, or all dates are lists.

---

For date intervals simply test (e.g. in an `if` statement):

```
begin <= date <= end
```

where all 3 values are as described above.

Comment: Feel free to downote, if you see something wrong, not helpful or misleading in my answer, but please leave a comment.